# «Женщина с мягкими трикотажными двойками». Особенности перевода

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, переводы, редактура, типы-ошибок

Из книги [**К. Аткинсон. Поворот к лучшему**](https://litresp.com/chitat/ru/%D0%90/atkinson-kejt/povorot-k-luchshemu/3) (перевод с английского  М. Нуянзиной):

> После обеда, в три часа пополудни, его секретарша (Джун или, может, Анджела), жизнерадостная молодая **женщина с** четким почерком и **мягкими трикотажными двойками**, приносила ему чашку чая с тарелкой печенья.

Такая фраза (мне она показалась некорректной) — это особенность английского текста или неточность перевода?
А как вы считаете — есть ли ошибка?

Comment: Если у вас есть возможность привести этот фрагмент в оригинале, то мы легко сможем ответить, как он должен был быть переведен на самом деле. Иначе придется только гадать и строить предположения.

Comment: Неточность перевода заключается в том, что по-русски так не говорят. И это не зависит от особенностей английского языка.

Comment: "Молодая женщина с четким почерком"— тоже не образец стиля, но "женщина с двойками" — щедевр!

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то не для нашего формата, это к переводчикам надо бы... Но попробую.

В оригинале так:

> And in the afternoon, at three on the dot, his secretary (June, or
>   perhaps Angela), a cheerful young woman with crisp shorthand and soft
>   **twinsets**, brought him a cup of tea and a plate of biscuits.

**twinsets** - это устоявшееся обозначение женской одежды, гарнитуры из кардигана и свитера (всегда удивлялся, как это можно сразу напялить на одну особу).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь лучше переводить как **"пара"**.
А **shorthand** - это **стенография**, в данном случае - "хрустящая" (crisp -"хрустящий", четкий).

А в остальном перевод передаёт особенность оригинала. В английском оригинале фраза столь же нарочито сконструирована, как и в русском переводе. Другое дело, что слово двойка по отношению к одежде - да еще женской - не сразу распознается. "Трикотажная пара" - много понятнее. 
Но сама грамматика ***"с прекрасной стенографией и трикотажной парой"*** полностью адекватна авторской задумке.

Answer (score 0):

Не видя оригинала судить трудно, но подозреваю, что имелось в виду:

> жизнерадостная молодая **женщина** с четким почерком, **обычно одетая в мягкие
>   трикотажные двойки**

Comment: Да кто ж вам мешает посмотреть оригинал? https://royallib.com/book/Atkinson_Kate/One_Good_Turn.html  Согласен, давать первоисточники - это проблема задающего вопрос, но в данном случае речь идет именно о переводе. Причем довольно известной книги популярного автора...